# Eclipse F5/Step Into Hotkey doesn't work with ubuntu >=12.10

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Since Ubuntu 12.10 `F5` for *Step into* is not working. Any ideas how to fix or debug that?
A friend has a similar problem (on Ubuntu 13.04 with Gnome3).

I already tried the following:

- Assign *Step into* to `F3` - works
- Assign any working hotkey to `F5` - doens't work
- Pressing `Meta` + `F5` on default mapping - works (that's interesting)

The last tipp I got from @rcjsuen at IRC. He gave me this [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/201711).

System Setup:

- Ubuntu 12.10 with Unity
- Springsourcetoolsuite 3.2.0.RELEASE what means Eclipse 3.8

Comment: Sounds like Gnome considers it a global hotkey.  Just to be certain.  Can "xevent" see the key press?

Comment: From which package i get xevent?

Comment: I was wrong - the right command name is "xev".

Answer (score 1):

As workaround i'm using `Meta` + `F5`. That is working.

But this is just a temporary solutions...